# To retrieve Year, Month and Day

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, format

How to retrieve year, month and day from the file name like `MONTUE-API-202310031200340313.TXT`

Below is the pattern which will not changed

```
MONTUE-API-{YEAR}{MONTH}{DAY}{TIMESTAMP}.TXT
```

I want to get `{YEAR}{MONTH}{DAY}` from this file name

```
MONTUE-API-202310031200340313.TXT
```

I am trying to get the output as `20231003`.

Thank you

Comment: `var output = input.Substring(11, 8);`

Comment: Or using a range `var output = input[11..19];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `substring` as commented by *Johnathan Barclay* in the question to achieve my desired result

```
var output = input.Substring(11, 8);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `substring` by getting the length after "MONTUE-API-" and extract the 8 digits for YYYYMMDD.

C# Example:

```
string fileName = "MONTUE-API-202310031200340313.TXT";
int startIndex = "MONTUE-API-".Length;
string dateTimeString = fileName.Substring(startIndex, 8);
```

Comment: Why programmatically obtain the length of `"MONTUE-API-"`? That's always going to be 11.

Comment: Your version is shorter, yes. But *subjectively speaking* it's just easier to read for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to use `Regex` and look for 8 digits after `MONTUE-API-` string.

Example is C#:

```cs
var match = Regex.Match(fileName, @"MONTUE-API-(\d{8})");
if(match.Success)
{
    var value = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

You can go further and also retrieve `year` `month` `day` by using more groups:

```cs
var match = Regex.Match(fileName, @"MONTUE-API-(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})");
if(match.Success)
{
    var year = match.Groups[1].Value;
    var month = match.Groups[2].Value;
    var day = match.Groups[3].Value;
}
```